# Read integers from text file and write to CSV file

Tags: beginner, bash, csv

**Background:**

I've recently started learning bash due to my new job in a VFX company. We backup all of our media to LTO tapes (one master and one clone). I was tasked with writing a script that split the tape list of master and clone to a CSV file. I feel I've done so in a crude manner as this was my first ever script and would love some feedback as to how I could improve the efficiency / syntax / code in general so I can learn from this experience.

Here is the text file: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AkWewdosAYGuhiaBbehlLBF64Qsg

I've been executing the script by calling it like this:
`$ sh /scriptname.sh filename.txt`

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script will split the presstore list of tapes into a .CSV file with two seperate coloumns.
file="$1"
echo "Splitting tape list....."
touch tempsplit.csv #creates temporary file for use later in script
while IFs= read line
do
    lastchar=$(echo $line | tail -c 2) 
        if [ "$lastchar" == : ]     #Ommits any lines that end with : else error
            then
                echo -ne
        elif [ "$lastchar" -ge 0 -a "$lastchar" -le 9 ]     #Selects lines that end in number
            then
                breakdown=$(echo "$line" | cut -d':' -f2,6) #selects fileds 2 & 6 containing tape numbers
                master=$(echo "$breakdown" | cut -d'a' -f1) #cuts first number
                clone=$(echo "$breakdown" | cut -d':' -f2) #cuts second  number
                final=$(echo -e "$master,$clone" | tr -d ' ' >> tempsplit.txt) #outputs to a temp csv file
        fi
done < $file
touch tapelist_split.csv
awk 'NR % 2 == 0' tempsplit.txt | sort -n >> tapelist_split.csv #removes every 2nd line, sorts numerically, converts to a .CSV file
rm -rf tempsplit.txt #removes tempfile
echo "Complete"
```

**Summary:**

I'm not sure why the while read statement doesn't work if I don't call `file="$1"` as in line 3 and again output to that varaible in line 20 `done < $file`- an explanation on this would be amazing.

I realise I shouldn't have to call my first if statement, as I only care about the numbers but if I don't I get an error: "integer expected" when I run the script - does anyone know why this might be.

The reason I create the file "tempslipt.txt" is because my code to remove every 2nd line and sort the file wasn't working within the wile read statement so I figured this was a clean way of doing it.

My code may not be very efficient or good which is why I'm asking for tips on how I can refine and correct it so in future I can write much cleaner scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brave attempt :-) This can be so much better ;-)

#### Running scripts

The script has the shebang `#!/bin/bash`, but you invoke it as `sh script.sh`.
The purpose of a shebang is to make scripts runnable as `./script.sh`.
When invoked this way, the shell looks at the shebang, and runs the script with the specified executable.
`sh` is often symlinked to Bash, but not always.

In short, if a script doesn't require Bash, then use the shebang line `#!/bin/sh` and run it as `./script.sh` or `sh ./script.sh`.
If it requires Bash, then use the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and run it with `./script.sh` or `bash ./script.sh`.

#### Filtering lines

Bash is not particularly well-suited to filter lines by patterns.
`grep` is a great tool for that.
So instead of reading line by line with Bash to filter,
look for ways to use `grep`.
In this example, replace the loop with:

```
grep '[0-9]$' "$file" | while IFS= read line; do
    ...
done
```

#### Empty conditional branches

I think your intention here was to do nothing when the condition is true:

> ```
> if [ "$lastchar" == : ]     
>     then
>         echo -ne
> elif ...
> ```

If you ever need to do nothing, you can use `true` or `:` like this:

```
if ...; then
    :
elif ...
```

But this is not a good example to use this trick,
because a better solution exists.
A better solution would have been to drop the `if`, and change the `elif` to `if`.
An even better solution would have been to call `continue` if the line doesn't match the required pattern, so the loop body would be flatter:

```
if ! [ "$lastchar" -ge 0 -a "$lastchar" -le 9 ]; then
    continue
fi

breakdown=...
```

With my tip with `grep` in the previous point, you don't need a condition at all.

#### Extracting two numbers

This is very inefficient:

> ```
> breakdown=$(echo "$line" | cut -d':' -f2,6)
> master=$(echo "$breakdown" | cut -d'a' -f1)
> clone=$(echo "$breakdown" | cut -d':' -f2)
> final=$(echo -e "$master,$clone" | tr -d ' ' >> tempsplit.txt)
> ```

The problem is that for each line this runs many processes: `echo`, `cut`, `tr`, and multiple `$(...)` sub-shells.

I see a simpler way to achieve what you want. Looking at these sample lines:

> ```
> tape with barcode: 000053 and is: offline at listed location: MCR Shelves and is: Full and is copy of tape with barcode: 000047
> tape with barcode: 000044 and is: offline at listed location: MCR Shelves and is: Full and is copy of tape with barcode: 000042
> ```

We could extract the two numbers and put a comma in between like this:

- Replace all non-digits at the beginning with empty string (= remove)
- Replace all non-digits with a comma

Try this simple pipeline:

```
grep '[0-9]$' file | head | sed -e 's/^[^0-9]*//' -e 's/[^0-9][^0-9]*/,/'
```

This works for the `head` of the file, but not the entire file. On closer look, there are lines that have a third number between the target numbers, which breaks the above pattern:

> tape with barcode: 000484 and is: online at listed location: i40 QUANTUM and is: Appendable and is copy of tape with barcode: 000483

After replacement this line becomes:

> 000484 and is: online at listed location: i40 QUANTUM and is: Appendable and is copy of tape with barcode: 000483

Observe that there is a space after the first number and before the last. So to handle such case, we could change the logic of the second step to: "replace everything between two spaces with a comma".

Let's give that a try, on lines containing "i40":

```
grep 'i40.*[0-9]$' file | head | sed -e 's/^[^0-9]*//' -e 's/ .* /,/'
```

It seems the script could be replaced with:

```
grep '[0-9]$' "$file" | \
    sed -e 's/^[^0-9]*//' -e 's/ .* /,/' | \
    awk 'NR % 2 == 0' | sort -n > tapelist_split.csv
```

No temporary files needed.

If you have the GNU version of `sed` (typically in Linux), then you can use it delete every 2nd line instead of `awk`, slightly simpler:

```
grep '[0-9]$' "$file" | \
    sed -e 's/^[^0-9]*//' -e 's/ .* /,/' -e '1~2d' | \
    sort -n > tapelist_split.csv
```

#### Quoting

When you use variables as command parameters,
it's important to double-quote them to protect from word splitting and globbing. So a loop should read from `$file` like this:

```
while ...; do ...; done < "$file"
```

#### Understanding command parameters

Why did you use the `-rf` flags here?

> ```
> rm -rf tempsplit.txt
> ```

There's no good reason to use those flags in the above script.

- The `-r` flag is to delete directories recursively. But the parameter above is a single file. The `-r` flag serves no purpose.
- The `-f` flag is to force deleting a file that might be protected, or to suppress error in case the file doesn't exist. Neither is the case here. The flag serves no purpose.

Flags in a script that serve no purpose or noise, confusing.
Understand all the flags you are using,
and make sure they have a reason to be there.

#### The field separator

The variable name is incorrect here:

> ```
> while IFs= read line
> ```

Should have been:

```
while IFS= read line
```

Variable names in Bash are case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you so much for this breakdown - exactly what I was looking for!

I shall take onboard this advice in future and try to improve, I feel I may have over complicated the task at hand.

The only further query I have is that; Whilst your sed solution is fantastic and certainly works for the most part, when lines such as:

`tape with barcode: 600172 and is: online at listed location: i80 Quantum and is: Appendable and is copy of tape with barcode: 600171`
 
this are the input, removing everything except numbers does not work - how best would you work around this?

Comment: @oshhee I updated my answer to handle that case